# How to arrange the image in grid view?

Tags: gridview, listbox, windows-phone-8

I want to order the image in grid view. I already use the listbox and add images into that successfully.It's display like below

[image]

But I want these images are display in grid view. It is Possible or not.

Please Help Me.... Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `LongListSelector` control for such purposes:

Add the namespace to your XAML:

```
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
```

Then put the `LongListSelector` on the page and set it up:

```
<phone:LongListSelector ItemsSource="{Binding IsoStorePics}"  LayoutMode="Grid" GridCellSize="60, 100">
    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="hello.jpg" Margin="5"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

Pay attention to the `LayoutMode` and `GridCellSize` properties. If you set `LayoutMode` to `Grid`, then you need to specify the `GridCellSize`, otherwise there'll be an exception.

For more examples of what you could do with the `LongListSelector` grid layout, see [this sample app](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/PhotoHub-Windows-Phone-8-fd7a1093) from Microsoft.

Comment: But here i have the following error                                    The type 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector' exists in both 'c:\Backup\SELVAM\photowrite\Bin\Debug\Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.dll' and 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.0\Microsoft.Phone.dll' C:\Backup\SELVAM\photowrite\obj\Debug\FromMedia.g.cs

Comment: How to set to visible the each cell border?.